# Titanium Android tab bar text color

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

How can I change the tab bar color text for android(i'm trying to set it to orange ) I can't seem to get it to change
I tried color,barcolor tried googling for it but no luck so far

Answer (score 1):

you can use with HTML format for change textColor

```
      TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabSpec tabName = tabHost.newTabSpec("Name");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
      tabName.setIndicator(Html.fromHtml("<font color=orange>Name</font>"),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_myphoto));
```

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial [Alloy Action Jackson](http://adampaxton.com/alloy-action-jackson-an-android-action-bar-demo-app-for-appcelerator-titanium.aspx) might provide you with a means to solve your issue. Personally, I would avoid using any reference to html (unless needed for a webview) because it doesn't compile into an native implementation which breaks the design pattern.